# Open Bootstrap modal clicking auto generated element

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I've got a problem to open Bootstrap 4 modal using element generated by Javascript. 
There are two very similar cards (identical but with diffrent id). First is hard coded in html doc (and work correctly). Another is generated by simple JS script. I try to use the same class name "openEditModal" but it doesn't work. Then I declared "data-toggle" "data-target" attributes for both but still work only hard coded card. Is there any possibility that Bootstrap JS file work only with hard coded element?

HTML Coded Card

```
<div class="row" id="all-contacts-box">
        <!-- ____EXIST_ADDRESSES____ -->
        <!-- addressBoxWrapper -->
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 mt-2 d-flex">
            <!-- addressBox -->
            <div class="card bg-light openEditModal label flex-fill">
                <!--contactHeader-->
                <div class="card-header pl-2 pt-1 font-weight-bold text-muted label-title">
                    Office Address
                </div>
                <!-- contactBody -->
                <div class="card-body row pt-0">
                    <!-- contactBodyLeft -->
                    <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center maps-pin">
                        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                    </div>
                    <!-- contactBodyRight -->
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <h4 class="label-title font-weight-bold">Main Name</h4>
                        <h5 class="label-address font-weight-normal">Street 22</h5>
                        <h5 class="label-address font-weight-normal">City, Country</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Part of JS Code that generate new card

```
var createContactBox = function(dataToDisplay, idCounter) {
  var mainAddressContainer = document.getElementById("all-contacts-box");
  var addNewBox = document.getElementById("add-new-box");

  var addressBoxWrapper = document.createElement("div");
  var addressBox = document.createElement("div");

  mainAddressContainer.insertBefore(addressBoxWrapper, addNewBox);

  addressBoxWrapper.appendChild(addressBox);
  addressBoxWrapper.classList = "col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 mt-2 d- 
 flex";
  addressBox.classList = "card bg-light openEditModal label flex-fill";

  addressBox.setAttribute("data-toggle", "modal");
  addressBox.setAttribute("data-target", "editBoxModal");
};

 $(".openEditModal").click(function() {
   $("#editBoxModal").modal();
 });
```

Comment: What about move 'addressBoxWrapper.appendChild(addressBox);' to be the last one in createContactBox function?

Comment: Unfortunately your tip does not work :(

Comment: Can you please send me a fiddle? jsfiddle/codepen?

Comment: Sure, here is an url [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Poul3R/xek4vLbz/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with dynamically created elements, is that they aren’t born with the same event handlers as the existing elements.

In order to fix it, you need to "refresh" the listeners after you add a dynamically element.

So I add events handlers to a function and turn it off before I turn it on (something like restart). If you don't turn it off, the event will triggered as many times this function is called, and you don't want it.

```
function refreshEvents() {
  $(".openEditModal").off();
  $("#add-new-box").off();

  $(".openEditModal").click(function() {
    $("#editBoxModal").modal();
  });

  $("#add-new-box").click(function() {
    $("#addNewBoxModal").modal();
  });
}
```

Now you can call this function whenever you create another element.
So I call it after you created the element.

This is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/xek4vLbz/12/)

Comment: This code work's nice but now I have another problem. I sent part of app and it works fot this small part but i have no idea how to use it in complete project. Here is a link to complete project [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Poul3R/sck7fjyb/4/).

Comment: I mean I used this code in full app but there are 2 types of auto generated cards. Firs is generated by function initialized on startup, and data for this card come from hard code array. Second type is card added by user - using "#addNewBoxModal" modal. After pass data into this modal I can create new box on my own but here is my main problem. I don't know how to implement "refreshEvents" function to  all card added by me. (I implemented "refreshEvents" to array-cards and it works really good).